# Coredata safe clear subEntities

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I want to ask for a safe way to clear subEntities in coredata.

I have my a many-to-many relationship like this: `Product *<->* Product`. Therefore, I've got to create a subEntity to hold some special values between (sortPosition, groupName.....).

So it's like this: `Product *<->1 ProductSubEntity 1<->*Product`.

When I download products from server's API, the easiest way to update correctly correspond to the server's result is:

1. Remove all child relationship (`[self removeProductSubEntities:self.subEntities]`).
2. Add sub from server's result.

Result: There'd be a lot of subEntity in coredata (which won't hold relationship to any product), and this might take storage/memory/cpu when CRUD (I think?). But I can't actual delete the subEntity (in case it's being hold reference to as an viewController's Object somewhere, and it might cause crash: access to a deleted object).

**QUESTION:**

How can I clear those sub entities (might occur sometimes) if:

1. No relationship to any product.
2. No actual reference from anywhere (any viewControllers or objects)???

P/S: I'm thinking of implement a batch delete when terminate app. Could that be consider a safe solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't consider this to be a datastore issue, rather a UI update issue. You should delete the objects from the datastore when you don't need them any more and you should update the UI accordingly.

1 thing you didn't mention is re-use. It's possible that your download may be an update to an existing item, which you could find and update, then life is easy all round. Arguably everything below still applies in this case though as your UI might not update to reflect changes and you may need to refresh the managed object.

For the UI update it's generally wise to observe the datastore for changes, usually with an `NSFetchedResultsController`. If you're doing this then your UI would automatically update itself with the changes.

If you're explicitly passing entity instances around then you should have some way to trigger an update explicitly, and exactly how that works depends on your UI. Generally speaking you'd be doing something like posting a `UINotification` to tell the system that the datastore changed and they need to re-validate their data objects. For the UI you shouldn't be showing now-dead objects to the user, and in your question where you talk about not deleting to avoid crashes, it's probably worse to allow the user to update invalid objects and just quietly not telling them that their updates won't be saved. When the notification is received you may want to pop a (some) controller(s) off the stack, or re-query the datastore for the new data to be displayed.

If for some reason you don't want to do the above, then yes, you can query for all of the entities with a nil relationship and then batch delete them. This should be done on a background thread just like data loading and I'd recommend doing it on app load instead of close (because you won't have so many view controllers loaded and the ones that are should all have only valid references now...).